# Efficiently copy non overlapping slices of the same vector in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec<T>` where `T: Copy + Clone` and I would like to efficiently copy a slice of the vector to another slice of the same vector, where slices have the same length and do not overlap. In C++ I would use [`std::memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) for the same purpose.

I would like to:

- avoid using unsafe functions like [`std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.copy_nonoverlapping.html)
- use a library function, without implementing the copy loop myself

What I have tried:

```
#[test]
fn copy_within_a_vector() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 0, 0];
    let src = &data[0..2];
    let mut dst = &mut data[3..4];
    dst.copy_from_slice(src);
}
```

This code does not even get compiled because the borrow checker complains about borrowing `data` both mutable and immutable at the same time (and it is right).

Is it possible to rewrite the code to compile on stable Rust?

Related questions:

- [Writing to multiple bytes efficiently in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938561/writing-to-multiple-bytes-efficiently-in-rust)
- [How to idiomatically copy a slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219231/how-to-idiomatically-copy-a-slice)

Comment: I think that the referred question is about cloning parts of the slice into new owned vectors, I wish not to allocate any new memory, just copy contents of a vector in place as it is

Comment: @ViktorChvátal: The solution is the same: create two, non-overlapping slices.  You can read from a mutable slice just fine.

Comment: Check out the [*second* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30278246/155423) (yes, sometimes reading past the first answer or first search result is the right thing to do).

Comment: Thank you, I missed that, using split_at_mut was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut). Then you can use [`clone_from_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice).

**Example of implementation:**

```
// split the slice in two mutable slices
// then copy one subslice to other
fn copy_within_a_slice<T: Clone>(v: &mut [T], from: usize, to: usize, len: usize) {
    if from > to {
        let (dst, src) = v.split_at_mut(from);
        dst[to..to + len].clone_from_slice(&src[..len]);
    } else {
        let (src, dst) = v.split_at_mut(to);
        dst[..len].clone_from_slice(&src[from..from + len]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = (0..10).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", v);
    copy_within_a_slice(&mut v, 6, 1, 3);
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

**Ouput:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Do not forget to pay attention to the values because the code will panic if you are out of bounds.

Comment: If you agree with the duplicate, don't answer the question. That just clutters up SO.

Comment: @Shepmaster I considered that the question is distant enough to possible duplicate. That's not an "exact duplicate".

Comment: @Boiethios It is enough for an answer in a duplicate to cover the solution to this question.

Comment: Thank you, @Boiethios, your answer shows a nice implementation of what I was willing to do, however, answers in duplicates already contain solutions to my question. Should I also accept this answer or leave it as it is?

Comment: @ViktorChvátal I do not know, I am looking for some source in meta.

Comment: @Boiethios Ok, on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/) I have found an advice "If you don't think the answers on the duplicate question are good enough, write an answer there." I consider your answer better suiting my needs, so I'm accepting it

Comment: @ViktorChvátal Got same answer there: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352195/4498831

Comment: @ViktorChvátal "If you don't think the answers on the duplicate question are good enough, write an answer there." — "there" means *on the duplicate **target***, not on the question that is being marked as the duplicate.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for pointing that out, I'm going to know next time